# math.js Uncaught TypeError: v is not a function with p5

Tags: javascript, p5.js, mathjs, math.js

I hate that I'm asking this question but I've been through every single stack overflow post tagged with [mathjs](/questions/tagged/mathjs) or [math.js](/questions/tagged/math.js) and a whole load of posts with "x is not a function" but none of them are relevant or helpful. Here is the full stack trace I get in Google Chrome:

```
Uncaught TypeError: v is not a function
    at p (math.js:1741)
    at typed (eval at p (math.js:1740), <anonymous>:15:16)
    at Object.r [as factory] (math.js:15041)
    at t (math.js:232)
    at Object.n [as factory] (math.js:30335)
    at t (math.js:232)
    at Object.n [as factory] (math.js:30256)
    at t (math.js:232)
    at Object.n [as factory] (math.js:29710)
    at t (math.js:232)
```

Notice how none of the error points to my code, and I get the same exact error if I try to call any math methods in the console.

I'm using p5.js just to make a little interactive thing for my website and I need the expression parsing functionality of math.js.

Here's my html file:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>2D plotter</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.3.0/math.min.js"></script> <!-- here's where I load math.js from a cdn -->
  <!-- PLEASE NO CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE (UNTIL I SAY SO) -->
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Function.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Plot.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="WebsitePlotter2D.js"></script>
  <!-- OK, YOU CAN MAKE CHANGES BELOW THIS LINE AGAIN -->

  <!-- This line removes any default padding and style.
       You might only need one of these values set. -->
  <style> body { padding: 0; margin: 0; } </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The "please no changes" lines were there when the Processing editor generated the original html file, and I haven't messed with it. And here the code that calls on the math.js library, although at this point I'm convinced it's irrelevant:

```
draw() {
  let lastPoint = null;
  let nx, ny, y;
  const parser = math.parser();

  stroke(this.lineColor);
  strokeWeight(this.lineWeight);
  for (let xv=this.plot.xStart; xv<this.plot.xStop; xv+=this.step) {
    parser.set('x', xv);
    y = parser.evaluate(this.func);
    ny = this.plot.scalePixelY(y);
    nx = this.plot.scalePixelX(xv);
    if (lastPoint !== null && 4) {
      line(lastPoint.xVal, lastPoint.yVal, nx, ny);
    }
    lastPoint = {xVal: nx, yVal: ny,};
  }
}
```

Also if I go to the lines in math.js referenced in the traceback there is no method call or even variable name of `v` so I'm not sure what's going on. Any help is appreciated, I want to put this silly error behind me.

Answer (score 0):

So I was battling this problem for like an hour, and of course I found the solution 10 minutes after creating a stack overflow question about it.

I just switched the CDN url to `"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/6.1.0/math.js"` and it worked. It makes me wonder why so much of the information about math.js is outdated.